# Unable to understand a line of Emacs Lisp

Tags: emacs, lisp

The line is

```
function info() { 
    emacs -eval "(progn (setq Man-notify-method 'bully) (info \"$1\"))" 
}
```

I know from manuals that

**Progn**

> progn is a special form in `C source
>   code'.

**Setq**

> setq is a special form in `C source
>   code'. (setq SYM VAL SYM VAL ...)
>
> Set each SYM to the value of its VAL.
>   The symbols SYM are variables; they
>   are literal (not evaluated). The
>   values VAL are expressions; they are
>   evaluated. Thus, (setq x (1+ y)) sets
>   `x' to the value of`(1+ y)'. The
>   second VAL is not computed until after
>   the first SYM is set, and so on; each
>   VAL can use the new value of variables
>   set earlier in the `setq'. The return
>   value of the`setq' form is the value
>   of the last VAL.

**$1** seems to a reference to the first parameter after the command `man` which the user gives.

**'bully** seems to be a random variable.

**Man-notify-method** seems to be an action function which is run when man command is executed.

`-eval` seems to be an evalutian statemant which tells Emacs to run the statement which follows it.

However, I am not completely sure about the function.

I need to understand the function, since I want to bind a *bash code of mine* to the action function of man. **Man-notify-method** seems to be that action function, at least in Emacs.

**How do you understand the line of Emacs Lisp?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

PROGN simply evaluates the expressions in order, returning the return value of the last one.

SETQ is the basic assignment operator.

INFO enters the emacs info browser.

So, what this does is first assign the symbol `'bully` to the variable `Man-notify-method`, then enter the info browser.  `'bully` is likely the name of a function, and `Man-notify-method` a place where the info browser looks up a function to call for some notification (Warning: I am just guessing here).

I guess that you will have to define your own function that calls your shell command like this:

```
(defun my-cmd ()
  (call-process   ; Look up the syntax in the emacs lisp manual
  ))
```

Then assign its symbol to `Man-notify-method`:

```
(setq Man-notify-method 'my-cmd)
```

Comment: I accept this answer, since it is compact. Adam's answer is also excellent. --- Thank you for your answers!

Answer (score 12):

The code you posted is a combination of shell script and elisp.

```
function info()
{
    emacs -eval "(progn (setq Man-notify-method 'bully) (info \"$1\"))"
}
```

This defines a shell script function named `info`.  It takes 1 parameter, named `$1`.  When you call this function (say, from another shell script), the value of the argument gets substituted in for `$1`, and it runs the commands specified in sequence.  So, if you were to call it like this:

```
info("something")
```

The shell would execute this command:

```
emacs -eval "(progn (setq Man-notify-method 'bully) (info \"something\"))"
```

This invokes the emacs executable with two arguments, `-eval` and the command string, which contains embedded escaped quotes.  This is asking emacs to invoke the following elisp code:

```
(progn (setq Man-notify-method 'bully) (info "something"))
```

`progn` is a *special form*.  Special forms evaluate their arguments differently than normal function calls.  You can find the documentation for `progn` in [chapter 10.1 of the GNU Emacs Lisp Reference Manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Sequencing.html#Sequencing).  `progn` is a simple construct for executing a sequence of statements in order.  The reason you may need to do this is for cases when you want to execute multiple statements, but the context that you're in only expects a single statement.

For example, an `if` statement takes 3 (or more) arguments: the condition to evaluate, the expression to evaluate if true, and the expression to evaluate if false.  If more than 3 arguments are provided, the subsequent arguments are part of the else branch.  If you want to use more than one statement in the true branch, you have to use `progn`:

```
(if condition
   (progn first-statement-if-true
          second-statement-if-true)
   first-statement-if-false
   second-statement-if-false
)
```

In this case, if `condition` is true, then `first-statement-if-true` and `second-statement-if-true` will be evaluated.  Otherwise, `first-statement-if-false` and `second-statement-if-false` will be evaluated.

Thus, your code will simply evaluate the two statements `(setq Man-notify-method 'bully)` and `(info "something")` in order.

`setq` is another special form.  See [chapter 11.8](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Setting-Variables.html#Setting-Variables) for its documentation.  It simply sets a variable, named by the first parameter, to the value of the second parameter.  The first parameter is *not* evaluated -- it is taken literally.

A value preceded by a single quote (such as `'bully`) is not evaluated.  See [chapter 9.3](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Quoting.html#Quoting) for details on quoting.  Hence, `(setq Man-notify-method)` sets a variable named `Man-notify-method` to the literal token `bully` (which is a data type called a *symbol*, which is distinct from the string `"bully"`).

I can't find the documentation on the `info` function online, you can get help on any given function in emacs by typing `C-h f function-name`.  So, by typing `C-h f info`, I got this:

> ```
> info is an interactive autoloaded Lisp function in `info'.
> [Arg list not available until function definition is loaded.]
>
> Enter Info, the documentation browser.
> Optional argument FILE specifies the file to examine;
> the default is the top-level directory of Info.
> Called from a program, FILE may specify an Info node of the form
> `(FILENAME)NODENAME'.
>
> In interactive use, a prefix argument directs this command
> to read a file name from the minibuffer.
>
> The search path for Info files is in the variable `Info-directory-list'.
> The top-level Info directory is made by combining all the files named `dir'
> in all the directories in that path.
> ```

The online reference manual is very useful, and emacs' interactive help is also indispensible.  If you don't understand what a particular function does, just `C-h f` it.